# Python Conexion MSSQL AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws, lambda

estoy tratando de conectar una funcion lambda en AWS, a una base de datos MSSQL sin resultados

Estoy usando la libreria pyodbc , pero me da los siguientes problemas

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
from os import getenv
import pyodbc    

conn =pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={./libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.1.0};SERVER='+rds_host+';DATABASE='+db_name+';UID='+name+';PWD='+password+'')
```

elif

Zip Folder

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lambda error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado la conexión en un contenedor docker y se ejecuta sin problemas

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: hi there, this is the Spanish version, welcome! So, you have 2 options: #1: translate your question to Spanish. #2: Move it to Stackoverflow.com Choose wisely my friend :D

Comment: Oh, no me habia dado cuenta, como puedo editar la consulta?? gracias

Comment: click aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/165423/edit

Comment: Todos esos problemas de dependencias te los puedes librar con zappa el busca la correcta version de mysql te dejo el link yo pase por eso anteriormente 
https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa

Comment: Verifica los security group y las vpc de tu función lambda, podría ser que simplemente no le estás llegando a la base de datos.